# What are the bare-minimum port-forwarding requirements for NAT Type Open on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, networking

Regarding network access requirements for a NAT Type of Open, Microsoft's [Xbox One NAT Error](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/networking/nat-error-solution) troubleshooter says this:

> If you're connected to a network through your workplace or school
>   network, ask the network administrator to open the following ports:
>
> - Port 88 (UDP)
> - Port 3074 (UDP and TCP)
> - Port 53 (UDP and TCP)
> - Port 80 (TCP)
> - Port 500 (UDP)
> - Port 3544 (UDP)
> - Port UDP 4500 (UDP)
>
> If you’re connected to a home network, you may need to open ports on
>   your network hardware yourself through port forwarding.

The list above makes some sense for users requesting access from a network admin, e.g.: on a school or work network. It's fairly possible that such institutional networks may block traffic in both directions on some of these ports.

However, on your home network, it's most likely that all outbound traffic is being allowed by default. Therefore, you should only need to do port forwarding for inbound traffic.

Some of the ports listed refer to services that I don't expect should be running on an Xbox normally. (53 and 80 especially - DNS and HTTP, respectively) Thus, the Xbox network traffic addressing those ports should all be outbound and therefore not require port forwarding for a home network.

I don't want to forward any more ports than my Xbox actually needs. So, which of these ports are actually receiving inbound traffic *and* essential to achieve an Open NAT Type?

Comment: For the record: **Forwarding Port 53 (DNS) is not necessary and could actually break your home network.** Found that one out the hard way. Haven't tried killing the other ports yet, but I'm now NAT Open with all of the above settings *except* 53.

Answer (score 1):

The [Portforwarding](https://portforward.com/networking/static-ip-xbox-one/) website is a tried and true source for this information. According to the linked page, the following ports need to be opened:

### TCP

- 53, 80, 3074

### UDP

- 53, 88, 500, 3074, 3544, 4500

Just remember to assign a static IP address to your Xbox One, and then assign those opened ports to that address per your router's settings. I don't see anything there about skipping certain ports, but I imagine that trial and error of closing certain ones until your NAT becomes restricted again could give you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have port forwarding only for 3074 (both TCP and UDP) and it works. I believe that other ports are needed for connections from Xbox to Internet - and those are allowed by default on home routers.

Note that Xbox actually does not even listen on TCP ports 80 and 53. Would not make sense as 80 is for WWW and MS could hardly expect being available. Same is true for 53 which is used by DNS.

As always: Do not open anything unless you know why! According to Internet sources port 3074 is used by "Xbox LIVE" and "Games for Windows - Live".

Comment: Just to be on safe side. I have static IPv4 address visible from Internet and IPv6 support.